# Different TEXTMETRIC values for same font on Windows CE and Windows 7

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts, gdi

I have C++ Win32 application that supports Windows CE 6.0 that uses the GDI to display text at different sizes clipped within rectangles. I have an issue where text is clipped in the CE version and not in the Windows 7 version and I followed it down to where I am using the tmAveCharWidth member of the TEXTMETRIC structure when scaling fonts.

I have code like this to get the tmAveCharWidth, and it turns out to be 8 on Windows 7 and 9 on Windows CE with the same font, which leads to problems in calculations later on. What could explain this difference?

```
LOGFONT logFont = {};
logFont.lfHeight            = -19;
logFont.lfWidth             = 0;
logFont.lfWeight            = FW_NORMAL;
logFont.lfCharSet           = DEFAULT_CHARSET;
logFont.lfOutPrecision      = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
logFont.lfClipPrecision     = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
logFont.lfQuality           = DEFAULT_QUALITY;
logFont.lfPitchAndFamily    = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;
::wcscpy_s(logFont.lfFaceName, LF_FACESIZE, faceName);

HFONT font = ::CreateFontIndirect(&logFont);
HDC hdc = ::CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
HGDIOBJ oldObj = ::SelectObject(hdc, font);
TEXTMETRIC metrics = {};
::GetTextMetrics(hdc, &metrics);

std::cout << metrics.tmAveCharWidth;
```

The font the program uses is added using AddFontResource() and I have used GetFontData() to check that the font I am creating with CreateFontIndirect() is actually using that font in both versions.

Comment: Maybe the fonts are different?

Comment: Why would the fonts be different? The program loads the same font file on both versions using AddFontResource().

Comment: They are different operating systems, the fonts may very well be different. I'm not saying they are, but it's certainly worth considering.

Comment: Yes, the operating systems do have different versions of the same fonts, but the font I am using in this progam comes from a .ttf file that the program downloads and loads with AddFontResource(). I have verified that GetFontData() returns the same font data on Windows CE and Windows 7 and it matches the font file I am expecting.

Comment: Fair enough then. One thing you could try is to calculate the width yourself - the docs for `TEXTMETRIC` say `tmAveCharWidth` is usually the width of the letter "x", so you could just use `GetTextExtentPoint32` to calculate that yourself.

Comment: That comes out to 9 on both systems, so that would work in most cases.  But the program also displays text in different languages, so I think I would need another way to calculate the average width that does not use the letter 'x' always.

Comment: I think the concept of an average character width is arbitrary at best. "WWWWW" in most fonts will be a lot wider than "xxxxx" or "lllll". Maybe there's a better way to do what you're trying to accomplish?